# Tracking remote branch - when to do it?

Tags: git, github

I understand how tracking remote branch works, however I have hard time understanding when is the proper situation to do it.

Would anyone be so kind to please share with me some guidelines on when you generally track a remote branch and when you do not? Perhaps there are some rules which you usually follow when making this decision?

Thank you very much in advance for any response,

Radek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real "functional" gain to using a remote tracking branch to a normal branch. But there are some significant "ease of use" type benefits:

- A remote tracking branch automatically knows which remote to push/pull to/from.
- A remote tracking branch will give you information on how far ahead / behind you are when you issue a `git status` command.
- You could say you save yourself making type-o mistakes in your git push/pulls because you are always going to be push/pull'ing from the correct remote

But, in my humble opinion, I don't find them that useful. I always tend to use push and pull like:

`git pull/push origin <branch-name>`

So I avoid the short-hand. This is just in case I haven't bothered to setup a tracking branch for whatever reason, then I always get it right.

As for git status... well, I just always use `git fetch` to stay up to date and `git log --graph --all --decorate --oneline` (aliased as `git lg`) to see exactly what is going on with all the branches.

So really, I believe this is up to your own preference. If you just want to set up your branch to remote track to save having to think about where you are pushing, then setup a remote tracking branch.... if you are happy to be more explicit all of the time, then IMHO don't bother :)